# Pythonic way to add to a set and care about if it worked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Often times I find that, when working with Pythonic sets, the Pythonic way seems to be absent.

For example, doing something like a dijkstra or a*:

```
openSet, closedSet = set(nodes), set(nodes)
while openSet:
    walkSet, openSet = openSet, set()
    for node in walkSet:
        for dest in node.destinations():
            if dest.weight() < constraint:
                if dest not in closedSet:
                    closedSet.add(dest)
                    openSet.add(dest)
```

This is a weakly contrived example, the focus is the last three lines:

```
if not value in someSet:
    someSet.add(value)
    doAdditionalThings()
```

Given the Python way of working with, for example, accessing/using values of a dict, I would have expected to be able to do:

```
try:
    someSet.add(value)
except KeyError:
    continue # well, that's ok then.
doAdditionalThings()
```

As a C++ programmer, my skin crawls a bit that I can't even do:

```
if someSet.add(value):
    # add wasn't blocked by the value already being present
    doAdditionalThings()
```

Is there a more Pythonic (and if possible more efficient) way to work with this sort of set-as-guard usage?

Comment: I'm not sure how your example relates to your question.  In the example, nothing is done if the item *is* in the set.  In some sense the point of sets is that when you add an item, you don't care if adding it "works", because sets aren't supposed to count duplicates; you're just putting the element in.  If you want to do something based on whether it isn't there before you add it, check that and do that thing before you add it.

Comment: a lookup is `0(1)` so why does checking matter? If you want more concise code, `someSet.add(value) if value not in someSet else doOtherThing()`

Comment: The additional "not" in the last example was a typo, fixed, although it should have been possible to deduce that by the fact that it was inconsistent with the previous three examples.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm using the set as a guard against doing action, I fixed the stray "not" in the last example and changed the faux-function name to make it clearer. And while the cost is O(1) that means the cost of doing a conditional AND an insert is O(2), and O(1) only means its amortized-consistent, it doesn't mean that it only costs one instruction.

Comment: @kfsone, I don't see any better,more efficient or more pythonic  way than simply checking and adding. If the cost of that is too high than maybe python is not what you should be using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The add operation is not supposed to also tell you if the item was already in the set; it just makes sure it is in there after you add it.  Or put another way, what you want is not "add an item and check if it worked"; you want to *first* check if the item is there, and if not, then do some special stuff.  If all you wanted to do was add the item, you wouldn't do the check at all.  There is nothing unpythonic about this pattern:

```
if item not in someSet:
    someSet.add(item)
    doStuff()
else:
    doOtherStuff()
```

It is true that the API could have been designed so that `.add` returned whether the item was already in there, but in my experience that's not a particularly common use case.  Part of the point of sets is that you can freely add items without worrying about whether they were already in there (since adding an already-included item has no effect).  Also, having `.add` return None is consistent with the general convention for Python builtin types that methods that mutate their arguments return None.  It is really things like `dict.setdefault` (which gets an item but first adds it if isn't there) that are the unusual case.

Comment: I understand that - but this feels unpythonic to me, in comparison to other operations, and in many of the cases where I've used a set, the Pythonic approach used elsewhere makes much more sense.

A set operation, lookup or addition, is O(1), assuming you understand that this means amortized constant - it's not constant, its variable, and it's not "1 instruction".

So `if v not in s: s.add(v)` is O(2). The C++ implementation of set-addition feels more pythonic to me, doesn't require an exception, and maintains O(1) for both patterns.

Comment: Erh, that sounded more adversarial than I intended, I'm reflecting on whether I'm perhaps just over-enamored on the idea of a single "pythonic way" :)

Comment: @kfsone: What other operations are you thinking of?  Also, I don't think you're correct about the O(1) vs. O(2).  If `s.add(v)` knew whether the add "succeeded", then it would have to check that somehow, which would be another "instruction", so that would be O(2) as well, it would just be hidden inside the add operation.

Comment: `O(1)` is not `1 instruction`. It's an amortized constant. In the case of a set, it's a hashing operation. http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/setobject.c?view=markup Look for "set_insert_key". The expensive part - the hash lookup - is always done, at which point the add is relatively cheap. So in essence, python's set.add() is really `if not v in s: s.insert(v)` already

Comment: @kfsone: Okay, but I guess I don't get what you're saying.  Insert is O(1).  Lookup is O(1).  Looking up the key and then inserting it is still O(1).  O(2) is the same as O(1).  It's a bigger constant, but in time-complexity terms that doesn't matter, and the constant cost of a single lookup operation is highly unlikely to be a performance problem in practice.  Either way, this is a separate issue from whether the code is Pythonic.

Comment: Well, in a nutshell: `d[v] = 1`. You wouldn't write `if not v in d: d[v] = None` before `d[v] = 1` because you know the dictionary reference (`d[v] = `) duplicates the work of the conditional anyway. The same thing happens with set.add() but it's not exposed so we *have* to do the duplication of work.

Comment: @kfsone: But, again, in that example you're not using the information about whether the key was already in there.  If you wanted that information, you would indeed use `if not v in d` to decide whether to do whatever *else* you wanted to do.

Comment: Again, it's very simple, not sure whether I'm explaining poorly or you're just not aware of how set operations work. For `setx.add(val)`, the expensive work is locating the insertion point and checking if it's already populated. Thus, when you write "if v not in setx: setx.add(v)" you're doing the expensive check twice. But if you want to make something conditional on whether or not the set contains a value, you /have/ to check. It feels like it would be more pythonic - as described clearly above - to be able to take conditional action based on whether add did work or not